# select from one table, count from another where id is not linked

Tags: mysql

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Expected Output

Open        | 2

Pending     | 0

Closed      | 0

so on....

I tried using this below query

```
SELECT d.status , COUNT(*) num,e.name  FROM table1 d  cross join table 2 e group by name;
```

Which resulted in

[image]

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a **left join**. This type of join shows all rows from the left table, even when no rows from the right table exist.

```
select t2.name, count(t1.id)
from table2 as t2
left join table1 as t1 on t2.name = t1.status
group by t2.name
```

Note you need to aggregate on a column from `table1` to produce the `0` desired, hence the `count(t1.id)`. `count(*)` will produce `1` even if there is no row from `table1`.

A **cross join** as you have in your query simply creates a Cartesian product of the two tables involved, resulting in every row from the left table joined with every row in the right table once.

Comment: above query is correct which gives open| 2 but i need in such a way that it displays all the names from table 2(Open,cancel, closed,fixed,hold,open,pending,reopen) and displays (2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0).

Comment: @JMR Thanks for the edit and you're completely right, I had the two tables mixed up. `table2` needs to be the left table, left-joined with `table1`. Fixed.

Comment: it results into (Open,cancel, closed,fixed,hold,open,pending,reopen)(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)....it is showing 1 in all other places..

Comment: Yes it is, sorry. Take a look at my most recent edit.